# SQL select a column2 based on values in column1 in two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
To_day     |   percent
-----------------------
  5        |     1.5

  8        |      2

2147483647 |      3
```

I want to write a SELECT that take a day, find fitted range in To_day column and give back Related percent. for example:

```
@day = 3 -------> percent = 1.5

@day = 5 -------> percent = 1.5

@day = 7 -------> percent = 2

@day = 15 ------> percent = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [percent]
FROM mytable
WHERE To_day >= @d
ORDER BY to_day
```

Comment: It's Worked. but this where expression : WHERE To_day >= @d   . Thank You!

Comment: @Mohsen Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you want.

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (to_day INT, [percent] FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (5,1.5);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (8,2);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (2147483647,3);

DECLARE @day INT = 15;

SELECT TOP 1 [percent]
FROM @t1
WHERE (to_day - @day) >= 0
ORDER BY (to_day - @day) ASC
```